# Will i loose my data after upgrading

Tags: backup, macos

I know Yosemite(Leaving public betas) is yet not out but i am little curious to clear out few doubts before hand. I have bought my new macbook pro retina 15 inch so i am not aware about few things. If i upgrade from Mountain Lion to Yosemite will I loose all my installed softwares? Data?

Even if loose those installed softwares, no worries. I can re-install them. I have the .dmg files. But what i am worrying is, will these old softwares for M.Lion work with Yosemite? Or i need to update them all.

Answer (score 1):

The system is clearly designed to take great pains to not lose your data, however whenever you rewrite the core part of the OS that is responsible for booting the system, that is the time when you are most likely to discover a problem:

- Your hard drive or hardware could be flakey and the volume of changes exposes a pre-existing problem that was un-noticed since it was only affecting non-vital files.
- Your unique set of software and settings has a bad effect when migrated to the new OS.
- Your apps you depend upon don't work well yet or ever with the new OS.
- Your command line tools might all get deactivated / moved so it really depends upon which package manager you use and how ready it is to use the new versions of the compiler tools from Yosemite. I would ask a second question with specific details if you want to research that aspect of the upgrade to 10.10.

If you don't have the time to back up fully and have tested your restore process, you might be better doing that and not upgrading to a new OS before upgrading. Or you can check the availability of help to assist in the very unlikely chance you have an issue and pay someone / recruit someone to help you over the bumps.

Answer (score 0):

You won't loose anything that isn't part of the system.

AFAIK, what worked on Mountain Lion/Mavericks is most likely to work on Yosemite. If you have some critical software you need, you might want to check for some feedback from other users who have done the upgrade.

For a packet-management tools there is [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [Macports](https://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Doesn't your first sentence mean "You can and might lose everything you brought to the bare system in an upgrade"?

Comment: For example I lost the python3 update I had. But not the apps in `/applications`, so if you meant that : yes !

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I have seen upgrades actually move files out of /Applications when the migration tool _knows_ that app is incompatible.